# Count by group in crystal reports

Tags: count, crystal-reports

I've made a SQL report that needs to do a bunch of different things, but my issue is as you can see in the picture I grouped patients, because several of them had multiple discharges and I need a count of total patients discharged. I have several other counts, but when I right click and insert summary it doesn't give me the option to select a group to do a count by. Is there a way to insert a count by the patient group?

[image]

Comment: If you're just trying to count the total number of patients then you can just do a `distinct count ({patient.ID})`

Comment: Hey Ryan. This is being pulled by transaction, so their will be duplicates of the people, so I grouped it by people, so I need a count of the patient group by name, because that will get rid of the duplicates.

Comment: Right, and  a `distinctCount()` summary will take care of that. Since it's a _distinct_ count, the duplicates will be ignored.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ryan's answer was correct. I just did a distinct count.