# Grouping results within SQL

Tags: sql, group-by

I was thinking about doing this in crystal, but am thinking about doing it another way now. This is the way I was thinking about doing it before.  [Count by group in crystal reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18020128/count-by-group-in-crystal-reports)

I am pulling by transactions and need a count of unique people, but in the report they want to show the count of individual people and then show their services below as shown in the image. What I'd like to do is somehow get a count of unique users that I could just throw in at the bottom. Crystal won't allow me to do a count by group and users will have duplicates in the format they want it displayed. I am hopping that I can group it in the code then just add it to the bottom of the report. I hope I'm getting across what I'm trying to accomplish. If I can somehow just add the total of unique users at the bottom of the report it will finish it for me. Thanks in advance.

[image]

```
select 

distinct p.patient_id,
pa.fname as 'Patient',
p.clinic_id,
p.service_id,
p.program_id,
p.protocol_id,
p.discharge_reason,
p.date_discharged

from patient_assignment p
join patient pa
on p.patient_id = pa.patient_id
where p.program_id not in ('TEST', 'SA', 'INTAKE' ) and (p.date_discharged between '2013-01-01 00:00:00.000' and '2013-06-01 00:00:00.000')
and p.patient_id not in ('00000004', '00001667', '00020354')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is too long for a comment.

SQL Queries have fixed columns.  You can't "just throw" a different type of row at the bottom.  Although there are SQL solutions (such as concatenating all the fields to make a single row), these are not very palatable.

Instead, here are some other ways.

You can run another query to get the count.

You can query the "result" set to get the count (perhaps after fetching all the rows).

You can do some minor coding work in the application.